# Перевод массива типа int в массив типа byte

Tags: java

Как перевести массив `int[]` в массив `byte[]` ? 
Допустим имея `int[] a = {29, 88 ,46};`нужно перевести в массив `byte[]` , что бы получилось `byte[] a = {29, 88 ,46};`

Comment: В общем случае int в byte не перевести...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] a = {29, 288, 46};
byte[] b = new byte [a.length];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b[i] = (byte)a[i];
}
```

Но учтите, что byte может принимать значения в промежутке `[-128; 127]`. То есть, если `a` равно `{29, 130, 46}`, то тогда `b` будет равно `{29, -126, 46}`.